# UDP/sockets not working - only a problem with Ubuntu

Tags: networking

I'm installing a package that I've installed on multiple other versions of Linux. Debian, Mint, Armbian, Rasbian. It worked fine on all of them, although getting the dependencies running was tricky sometimes.

However, on Ubuntu (server, 20.04) the package installs quite easily but then gives me UDP/Socket errors when it runs.

```
INFO    2023-01-04 10:56:46,082 - iso15118.secc.comm_session_handler (217): Comm                                                             unication session handler started
INFO    2023-01-04 10:56:46,095 - iso15118.secc.transport.tcp_server (109): TCP                                                              server started at address fe80::31b3:d7:6173:4f8d%eth0 and port 59968
WARNING    2023-01-04 10:56:46,095 - iso15118.secc.transport.tcp_server (124): C                                                             losing TCP server
ERROR    2023-01-04 10:56:46,097 - iso15118.shared.utils (126): [Errno 1] Operat                                                             ion not permitted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rock/iso15118-master/iso15118/shared/utils.py", line 124, in wait_                                                             for_tasks
    task.result()
  File "/home/rock/iso15118-master/iso15118/secc/transport/udp_server.py", line                                                              112, in start
    sock=await self._create_socket(self.iface),
  File "/home/rock/iso15118-master/iso15118/secc/transport/udp_server.py", line                                                              75, in _create_socket
    sock.setsockopt(
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rock/iso15118-master'
(iso15118-py3.9) rock@rock-4c-plus:~/iso15118-master$
```

I've turned off the firewalls completely, with ufw and iptables.

I'm sure this is something silly, but I don't know what it is. Any ideas??  This is on a Rock 4c+ - a Pi clone.

H

Comment: Hi. I was really saying that I was using 20 rather than 22. But having checked it's 20.04

It's a specific Rock 4c+ build. from this page. https://github.com/radxa/debos-radxa/releases/tag/20230101-1010

But it's basically 20.04, LTS, Ubuntu server.

Comment: Googling brought us to a page for a completely different software package that had a similar problem. They didn't specifiy if it was Ubuntu or not. But this command fixed their problem...and worked for us too. 

sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /usr/bin/python3.9

As I mentioned, this wasn't needed on any other version of linux that I've used this package on.

Comment: And this isn't on Ubuntu Core....just Ubuntu Server, 20.04 LTS.